# What do the numbers for "awarded" mean for badges?

Tags: support, badges, statistics

On main page `Badges` indicates that for [Mortarboard](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/badges) 261 have been awarded:

[image: main]

On meta the number is shown as [2](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges):

[image: meta]

What do these numbers signify, if anything - in particular the `2` for meta -  given the badge is for:

> Earn at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day

and on meta rep is the same as on main (supposedly).

---

I think [Meta participation vs main reputation and associated badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181971/meta-participation-vs-main-reputation-and-associated-badges) may be related to the above, but it too shows no answer.

Perhaps meta should not display badges that can no longer be achieved on meta. (ie leave the `2` as is but for meta don't display the 'Mortarboard' row at all.)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you can still earn the mortarboard on meta...just earn 200 rep on meta in a day...no?

Comment: perhaps it can still be obtained for 'earning' 200 but doesn't show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prompted by [@Mark Mayo's Comment](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4233/what-do-the-numbers-for-awarded-mean-for-badges?noredirect=1#comment12984_4233) (many thanks!) I have reverted to this 'afresh' rather than merely baffled. Following a lengthy trail I eventually came to [@rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253301)'s post.

As I understand it at present, when separate meta reputation was abandoned, the background number crunching was left as it was. That is, scores are still 'earned' for meta posts - they are merely no longer displayed. These 'hidden scores' may still lead to badges that *are* displayed. Hence, for example, receipt of 20 upvotes on meta answers in one SE day (and no down votes) would trigger the award of a `Mortarboard` badge even now. So there is reason to retain the `Mortarboard` listing for meta. Just that for meta the description:

> Earn at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day

has an implied *hidden* between *200* and *reputation*.